# Save Image generated with Reportlab in my MEDIA folder (in Amazon S3)

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3, reportlab

I implemented this library for generate barcodes images (http://kennethngedo.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/how-to-generate-barcode-in-django-using-reportlab/)

Everything works fine, the image is generated correctly, BUT... the image is created in a folder outside the project, and such I'm using Heroku for Production, I can't access to the image.

I'm using this Django structure (http://django-skel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) specially adapted to work on Heroku with Amazon S3.

Do you know guys how can I upload the generated image on my Media folder on Amazon?

This is my **Views.py** where the image is created and saved:

```
from random import randint
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import *
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing, String
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


class MyBarcodeDrawing(Drawing):
    def __init__(self, text_value, *args, **kw):
        barcode = createBarcodeDrawing('Code128', value=text_value, barHeight=10*mm, humanReadable=True)
        Drawing.__init__(self,barcode.width,barcode.height,*args,**kw)
        self.add(barcode, name='barcode')


def barcode_generator(barcode_value):
    text = barcode_value
    filename = "nightology_barcode_" + barcode_value
    path_to_save = "media/barcodes/"
    b = MyBarcodeDrawing(text)
    b.save(formats=['gif','pdf'],outDir=path_to_save,fnRoot=filename)
    barcodePicUrl = "barcode/"+ filename + ".gif"
    return barcodePicUrl
```

I hope somebody could help me on this... I'll really appreciate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar Problem but without the Amazon S3 part. For me it was really easy to create a new File in the media folder. I could simply use default_storage to get the path to the media folder:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
import os

# Get the path to the barcodes folder in the media folder
# check if the folder exists and create it if not

folderPath = default_storage.path('barcodes')
if not default_storage.exists('barcodes'):
    os.mkdir(folderPath)
```

Since django-skel seems to be using a django-storage backend for Amazon S3 this should also work for your setup. If the Amazon S3 storage backend is not the default storage backend, you might have to use the `S3Storage` class directly.

Comment: I noticed I had the folder name 'reports' when checking wether the path exists. Corrected that to be 'barcodes' as in the line above.